# writeOGR KML attributes blank

Tags: shapefile, r, kml, rgdal

Using the below I output a KML file from a Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

```
polygonWGS <- spTransform(Polygon, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 
+datum=WGS84"))  
writeOGR(polygonWGS, dsn="polygonWGS1.kml", layer="Area", driver="KML", 
overwrite = TRUE)
```

However, the resulting attributes table is blank in this KML. Specicially I'm interested in having the polygons named as the 'Area' name.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show us a bit more info about your `Polygon` object? Maybe it doesn't have any attributes? `summary(Polygon)` and `summary(polygonWGS)`  would help enormously if you can't demonstrate your problem with data you can share or other public data.

Comment: If I use Polygon@data and PolygonWGS@data the output is a list of 'Areas' with their full name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sf` package:

**Reproducible example**

```
# simple example, from scratch:
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
plot(SpP, col = 1:3, pbg="white")

grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as(grd, "SpatialPolygons")
centroids <- coordinates(polys)
x <- centroids[,1]
y <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
ex_1.7 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys,
                                   data=data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z, row.names=row.names(polys)))
```

Now, save it with `sf`:

```
library(sf)

st_write(st_as_sf(ex_1.7),'layer_name.kml', driver = 'kml')
```

[image]

Comment: the names of the layer don't show up in the table of contents and this info screen doesn't update when I double-click on a new polygon to navigate there. If you have experience filling in the name attribute of the kml so that it appears in the table of contents, consider my question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415464/label-kml-features-using-st-write